# Is this a valid XQuery?

Tags: xml, xquery

List the names of all mayors of someCountry

```
for $x in doc("Politics.xml")/Politician/CurrentMayor
where $x someCountry/name = 'Canada'      
return $x/name
```

Is there where part allowed?

Comment: What happens when you run it? Thats probably the best way to be sure.

Comment: I totally agree with @LegoStormtroopr. However, to still answer your question: No, it is not. What is the context of `someCountry/name`? You might want to do something like `$x/shomeCountry/name = 'Canada'`, although it is unclear what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not actually need the `for` expression, as you can evaluate the query in a single step by using a Predicate instead of the `where` clause. For example

```
doc("Politics.xml")/Politician/CurrentMayor[someCountry/name eq "Canada"]/name
```

I am assuming that `someCountry` is a child element of `CurrentMayor`, it was not entirely clear from your question as it has some syntactic mistakes.